# Yii2 - Select where month and year using yii/db/Expression

Tags: mysql, yii

In common query, we can use select a record or a lot of records using query like this

```
SELECT * FROM tagihan_cleaning 
   WHERE YEAR("ditagihkan_bulan") = 2017  AND 
         MONTH("ditagihkan_bulan") = 06
```

Now, In yii2, I have a dateInput , which is 06-2017.
Then, How to use Activerecord just query above.So far, I wonder like this:

```
 TagihanCleaning::find()->where([
               'ditagihkan_bulan' => MONTH('ditagihkan_bulan')
            ])->all();
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you dateinput is string  name $your_date_input, for an activeRecord,  you could use 
 a liter where and binding

```
  TagihanCleaning::find()->where(' YEAR("ditagihkan_bulan") = YEAR(str_to_date(:your_date_input1, "%m-%Y")
                  AND MONTH("ditagihkan_bulan") = MONTH(str_to_date(:your_date_input2, "%m-%Y") )
            ->bindValue(':your_date_input1', $your_date_input)
            ->bindValue(':your_date_input2', $your_date_input)
            ->all();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use directQuery:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tagihan_cleaning 
   WHERE YEAR("ditagihkan_bulan") = 2017  AND 
         MONTH("ditagihkan_bulan") = 06')
            ->queryAll();
```

With Prepared statement:

```
$post = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM tagihan_cleaning WHERE YEAR("ditagihkan_bulan")=:year AND MONTH("ditagihkan_bulan")=:month')
           ->bindValue(':year', '2017')
           ->bindValue(':month', '06')
           ->queryOne();
```

Comment: did you try this? @Fadly Dzil

Comment: Oke, I'll try it

Comment: Sadly, it gives an error like this :
Call to undefined function app\\modules\\finance\\controllers\\MONTH()

Comment: Thanks, but still error. Syntax error or access violation: 1305 FUNCTION ydepotras_finance.DATEPART does not exist.

Comment: You can use this solution @Fadly Dzil